# Extracting multiple tables from a PDF file and converting it to dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I have a 5 page pdf file, each page has a few tables that I need extract. I need to extract all the tables from each page and save them as a data-frame file all using python

I tried many things but couldn’t achieve this, please help

Answer (score 0):

Give "camelot" a try and search for examples here on stackoverflow.
https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot